# which version of mysql is running on MAMP for Magento 2 installation?

Tags: magento2, database, mamp

I updated MAMP to version 4.2 which has Mysql version 5.6.35 however when going through the Magento 2 installation I get the following error
[image]

what version of mysql am I actually running? should I upgrade? thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe still pointing to your old mysql version despite update, did you check mamp to see what version it says mysql is?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `mysql --version` from the command line, it will echo your version.

```
# Example for OSX
[user@host ~]$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --version
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

@nshiff it gives me
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper